# How to add specific tag to url using PHP?

Tags: php, html

For example:
I have

```
https://example.com/001.jpg

https://example.com/002.jpg

https://example.com/003.jpg

https://example.com/004.jpg
```

and so on 
I want to convert it to

```
<img src="https://example.com/001.jpg"/>
<img src="https://example.com/002.jpg"/>
<img src="https://example.com/003.jpg"/>
<img src="https://example.com/004.jpg"/>
```

USING PHP

How do i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean? `< img src="https://example.com/001.jpg" / >` wouldn't resolve to your server if it were in the URL.

Comment: I mean,i want to add <img src=" "/> to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want url from link use get and if
 from a form then use post

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo "<img src='$url' >";
```

Use $_POST if you get the url from the form submited.

Comment: It's Worked !! Thank you :)

Comment: @Enuma This will open you to XSS injections.

Comment: @Enuma Further you can use bind param and hashing to prevent sql injection if you are doing this on some  official platform

Comment: @AliveColdJuan Those are for SQL injections, not XSS. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS). Should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php with the `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: Thank you guys,i'm using this on localhost,not official platform !